How to get active object of revit application in windows application
I have to craete revit application for ifc export but withou creating pluddin or addin.I have to craete deskstop application . how can i do this?
do not open revit how can run in windows application ,i have to run revit at backend
I have tried with plugin but now i have to create without plugin.

Use of the Revit API requires an installation and a running session of Revit.exe. Please read the getting started material or the developers guide introduction for more information.
